# Verbose response after install conda package

Tags: python, command-line, anaconda, conda

I've encountered the following problem when I attempted to install a couple of packages. I'll use **sqlite3** as an example.

When I entered `conda install -c blaze sqlite3` in the Anaconda prompt ("base" environment), I received the output below.

I'm uncertain exactly when this problem started. I checked my revisions using `conda list -r`. Revision #35 - `conda  {4.8.3 (conda-forge/win-64) -> 4.8.3 (anaconda/win-64)}` - looks odd.

Therefore, I entered `conda install revision 34`. When I did so, I was informed that `conda-forge/win-64` cannot be found, which seems strange. As mentioned earlier, I'm unclear if there's a correlation between revision 34 and this error.

The **sqlite3** package listed in the "base" environment in the Anaconda Navigator.

How do I prevent **conda** from automatically running the additional code?

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: /
Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - anaconda/win-64::conda-4.8.3-py37_0
  - defaults/win-64::conda-4.8.3-py37done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\morga\Anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - sqlite3


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  sqlite3            blaze/win-64::sqlite3-3.8.6-0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

C:\Users\morga>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1

C:\Users\morga>SET MSSdk=1

C:\Users\morga>SET platform=

C:\Users\morga>IF /I [AMD64] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\Users\morga>IF /I [] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\Users\morga>if defined platform (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )  ELSE (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )

C:\Users\morga>for /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" /v InstallDir') do SET "VSINSTALLDIR=%B"
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

C:\Users\morga>if "" == "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=" )

C:\Users\morga>if "" == "" (
ECHO "WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
 GOTO End
)
"WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
The system cannot find the batch label specified - End
```

<<<<EDIT - ADDITIONAL COMMENT>>>

I did more research it seems that the package  `vs2015_win-64` is causing the problem. Others had similar experiences.

I executed `conda uninstall  vs2015_win-64`. The uninstallation was initiated then stopped and I received the error below.

The same thing occurred when I tried to install plotly using `conda install plotly`.

```
Error processing line 1 of C:\Users\morga\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-3.1.0-py3.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\morga\Anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 580, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `conda install sqlite=3`? The `sqlite3` packages are all from non-standard channels and terribly old.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely this has anything to do with the change in the `conda` package in that revision (where it switched from sourcing at Conda Forge to Anaconda channel). Instead, some packages include [additional installation scripts](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/link-scripts.html) that must be run during installation for the package to function. There is currently not any way to prevent Conda from executing such scripts.

It might be worth reflecting here that this is a good example of why one should not install packages from channels that one does not explicitly trust. That is, searching Anaconda Cloud to find a package on a random user channel could lead to running arbitrary code that the user has included in the package build.